# Why do I keep geting: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4

Tags: java, string-length

I'm new to java and I keep getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4"
```

I've read similar questions on here, and tried to apply the fixes but none of them seem to work. Maybe I'm applying them wrong?

The error I get points to the line of code indicated by <<<<<<<<<

But the method I'm editing that caused the error to appear is indicated by ******

The code used to compile and run just fine before I added the defaultHolidays method (the method I'm editing that is causing the error). The goal of this method is to take the contents of a file and display them on the calendar that is printed to screen via an array. The contents of the file look like this:

```
1/1 New_Year's_Day
01/18 M_L_K_Day
and so on
```

Here's my code, sorry it's so long:

```
   // Import general tools
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;  // Import the File class
import java.util.*;
   // Import tools to get current date
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;



   // Start of class
public class RCal3Winter21 {


       // Start of main method
   public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException { 
         // define the basics
      String[][]  strEventArray = new String[12][]; // creates the array to be filled later
         // helps run or break out of the program
      int intRunCode = 1; 
         // helps prevent invalid input 
      int intRequestedMo = 15;   
         // greet the user
      System.out.println();
      System.out.printf("%30s %n", "Welcome to CalintEndar!");
      System.out.printf("%36s %n", "~ for all your planning needs ~");
      System.out.println();
            // indicates how many boxes(days) are associated with each month
      strEventArray = sizeOfArray (strEventArray); 
         //begin program in earnest
      runMenu(intRequestedMo, strEventArray);
   } // intEnd main method


      // compiles on scratchpaper
      // removes leading zero from month & converts to int
   public static int noZoMo(String strTempDate) {
         //break temp date string into individual chars
      char month0 = strTempDate.charAt(0);
      char month1 = strTempDate.charAt(1);
      char slash = strTempDate.charAt(2);
      char day1 = strTempDate.charAt(3);
      char day2 = strTempDate.charAt(4);  <<<<<< This is the line the error highlights
      String strMo;   
         // If/else to display month w/out leading 0s
      if (month0 == '0') {
         strMo = String.valueOf(month1);
      } else {
         strMo = String.valueOf(month0) + String.valueOf(month1);
      } // End of if/else loop to display month w/out leading 0s      
         // converts month from string to int
      int intMo = Integer.parseInt(strMo);
       // returns month without leading zeros
      return intMo;
   }
      
      
      
      // compiles on scratchpaper
      // removes leading zero from day & converts to int
   public static int noZoDay(String strTempDate) {
         //break temp date string into individual chars
      char month0 = strTempDate.charAt(0);
      char month1 = strTempDate.charAt(1);
      char slash = strTempDate.charAt(2);
      char day1 = strTempDate.charAt(3);
      char day2 = strTempDate.charAt(4); 
      String strDay;   
         // If/else to display day w/out leading 0s
      if (day1 == '0') {
         strDay = String.valueOf(day2);
      } else {
         strDay = String.valueOf(day1) + String.valueOf(day2);
      } // End of if/else loop to display day w/out leading 0s      
         // converts day from string to int
      int intDay = Integer.parseInt(strDay);
          // returns day without leading zeros
      return intDay;
   }



      // compiles in scratchpaper
      // displays the menu and gather's the user's response
      // returns response as a string to be worked with
   public static String menuDisplay() {
         // prints menu and prompts for input
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Please pick from the menu below");
      System.out.println("\t\"e\" to enter a date and display it's calendar.");
      System.out.println("\t\"ev\" to input an event.");
      System.out.println("\t\"fp\" to save your calendar to a file");
      System.out.println("\t\"t\" to get today's date and display today's calendar");
      System.out.println("\t\"n\" to display the next month");
      System.out.println("\t\"p\" to display the previous month");
      System.out.println("\t\"q\" to quit CalintEndar");
         // Scanner to gather user input
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
         // assigns user input to string
      String command = in.nextLine(); 
         // ignores case used
      command = command.toLowerCase(); 
         // returns the user input
      return command; 
   } // intEnd menueDisplay method



      // can't run in scratchpaper, too many method calls
      // converts the user input to actions
   public static void runMenu(int intRequestedMo, String[][]  strEventArray) throws FileNotFoundException {
      // method tools   
      boolean booRunProg = true; // value continues to run or breaks out of while loop
      String strUsrInput;
         // while loop to run menu selection & allow exit
      while (booRunProg == true) { 
         strUsrInput = menuDisplay(); // sets input val frm menuDisplay to local str
                                      // for use in this method/while loop
         switch (strUsrInput) { // checks user input against menu options
            case "e": // user requests specific date
               intRequestedMo = optionE(strEventArray);
               break;
            case "t": // user requests today's date
               intRequestedMo = optionT(strEventArray);
               break;
            case "n": // user wants to see the next month
               intRequestedMo = optionN(intRequestedMo, strEventArray);
               break;
            case "p": // user wants to see previous month
               intRequestedMo = optionP(intRequestedMo, strEventArray);
               break;
            case "ev": // user wants to add event
               strEventArray = optionEV(strEventArray);   
               break;
            case "fp": // user wants to save event
               optionFP( strEventArray);
               break;
            case "q": // user wants to quite program
               System.out.println("Thanks for using Calendar!");
               booRunProg = false;
               break;
            default: // user made an error, try again
               System.out.println("Invalid command. Please try again.");
               break;
         } // end switch case
      } // end while loop
   } // end runMenu method



      // runs in scratchpaper, but without method call
      // user enters a requested date
   public static int optionE(String[][]  strEventArray){
         // Prompt user
      System.out.println("What date would you like to see? (mm/dd)"); 
         // Scanner to gather user input
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
         // set user input to a string
      String strTempDate = input.next();
         // remove the leading zeros from the current date
      int intRequestedMo = noZoMo(strTempDate);
         // returns the value of the current date as a string
      drawCalnDate(strEventArray, intRequestedMo);
      return intRequestedMo;    
   } // end optionE method



      // runs in scratchpaper without method call
      // show today's date
   public static int optionT(String[][]  strEventArray) 
               throws FileNotFoundException {
            // get current date
      DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd");
      LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
         // convert current date information to a string
      String strTempDate = dtf.format(now);
         // remove the leading zeros from the current date
      int intRequestedMo = noZoMo(strTempDate);
      defaultHolidays(strEventArray, intRequestedMo);         
      drawCalnDate(strEventArray, intRequestedMo);
         // returns the value of the current date as a string
      return intRequestedMo; 
   } // end optionT method
   
   
      
      // runs in scratchpaper w/out method calls
      // user wants to see the next month
   public static int optionN(int intRequestedMo, String[][]  strEventArray) 
         throws FileNotFoundException {
         // making sure there's a calendar on the screen   
      if (intRequestedMo == 15) {
         System.out.println("Error. Must select a calendar first.");
         return intRequestedMo;    
      } // end if
      else { // ensure cal goes from december to january
         if (intRequestedMo == 12){
            intRequestedMo = 1;
            defaultHolidays(strEventArray, intRequestedMo);   
            drawCalnDate(strEventArray, intRequestedMo);   
         } else {
            intRequestedMo++;
            defaultHolidays(strEventArray, intRequestedMo);   
            drawCalnDate(strEventArray, intRequestedMo);
            return intRequestedMo; 
         } // end else
      }// end first if
      return intRequestedMo; 
   } // end optionN method
   
   
   
      // runs in scratchpaper w/out method calls
      // user wants to see previous month
   public static int optionP(int intRequestedMo, String[][]  strEventArray)
      throws FileNotFoundException {
                  // making sure there's a calendar on the screen   
      if (intRequestedMo == 15) {
         System.out.println("Error. Must select a calendar first.");
         return intRequestedMo; 
      } else { // ensure cal goes from january to december
         if (intRequestedMo == 1){
            intRequestedMo = 12;
            defaultHolidays(strEventArray, intRequestedMo);   
            drawCalnDate(strEventArray, intRequestedMo);                  
         } else {
            intRequestedMo--;
            defaultHolidays(strEventArray, intRequestedMo);
            drawCalnDate(strEventArray, intRequestedMo);
         } // end second if/else
      } // end first if/else 
      return intRequestedMo; 
   }
   
   
   
         // user wants to add an event
   public static String[][] optionEV (String[][] strEventArray) throws FileNotFoundException {
         // create scanner
      Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);         
         // prompt for date for the event
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("When is the event? (mm/dd format)");
         // get date from user
      String strNewEvDate = userIn.next();
         // remove zeros and change to ints
      int intMo = noZoMo(strNewEvDate);
      int intDay = noZoDay(strNewEvDate);   
         // prompt for event name
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("What's happening?");
      System.out.println("Title the event in event_name format.");
      System.out.println("19 characters or less");         
         // get event name from user
      String strNewEvent = userIn.next();   
            // puts event in array
      strEventArray[intMo-1][intDay-1] = strNewEvent;   
         // return updates to  strEventArray
      return  strEventArray;            
   } // end optionEV method
   
   
   
      // user wants to print a month to file
   public static void optionFP(String[][]  strEventArray) throws FileNotFoundException {
            // create scanner
      Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
         // prompt user
      System.out.print("What month would you like to print to a file?");
            // get user input
      int printMonth = userIn.nextInt();
      //<<
         
   } // end optionFP method     


   public static String[][] defaultHolidays (String[][]  strEventArray, int intRequestedMo) *********
      throws FileNotFoundException {
      File readFile = new File("defaultHolidays.txt"); // checks for file to be read
      String strFileDate = "temp";
      String strFileEvent = "temp";
      String event;
      String date;
      int intFileMo = 0;
      int intFileDay = 0;      
         // new scanner to read the file
      Scanner input = new Scanner(readFile); 
         //System.out.println();
         // to print the file to the screen
      while (input.hasNext()) {
         date = input.next();
         strFileEvent = input.nextLine().trim();
         if (date.length() != 4) {
            System.out.println("There is an error in the file");
            System.out.println("Date must be in mm/dd format");   
         } else {
            intFileMo = noZoMo(date);
            intFileDay = noZoDay(date);
            strEventArray[intFileMo-1][intFileDay-1] = strFileEvent;
         }              
      } // end while        
      return strEventArray;
   
   
   } // end method defaultHolidays




   public static String[][] sizeOfArray (String[][]  strEventArray) {
         
      strEventArray[0] = new String[31];
      strEventArray[1] = new String[28];
      strEventArray[2] = new String[31];
      strEventArray[3] = new String[30];
      strEventArray[4] = new String[31];
      strEventArray[5] = new String[30];
      strEventArray[6] = new String[31];
      strEventArray[7] = new String[31];
      strEventArray[8] = new String[30];
      strEventArray[9] = new String[31];
      strEventArray[10] = new String[30];
      strEventArray[11] = new String[31];
      
      return strEventArray;
   
   } // end method to indicate num boxes in each array "row"



         // indicates how many days are in each month
   public static int daysInMo(int intRequestedMo) {
        // if then to determine number of days in month
      if (intRequestedMo == 4 || intRequestedMo == 6 ||
       intRequestedMo == 9 || intRequestedMo == 11) {
         return 30;
      } 
      else if (intRequestedMo == 2) {
         return 28;
      } 
      else {
         return 31;
      }
   } // end daysInMonth method  
   
   
   
       // method to display month on top of calendar
   public static void topDateDisp(int intRequestedMo) {
      // declarations   
      String centSngl;
      String centDbl;
      String mon = "Monday";
      String tue = "Tuesday";
      String wed = "Wednesday";
      String thu = "Thursday";
      String fri = "Friday";
      String sat = "Saturday";
      String sun = "Sunday";   
         // if to account for double digits
      if (intRequestedMo > 0 && intRequestedMo < 10) {
         for (int i = 1; i <= 71; i++) { // for to center
            System.out.print(" ");
         } // end for to center month
         System.out.println(intRequestedMo);
      } // end if for single digit
      else {
         for (int i = 1; i <= 70; i++) { // for to center
            System.out.print(" ");
         } // end for to center month
         System.out.println(intRequestedMo);
      } // end else if double digit
        // line break for aesthetics
      System.out.println();
         // print the days of the week at the top of the calendar
      System.out.printf("%13s%21s%21s%19s%19s%21s%18s %n", mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun );   
   }  // end topDateDisp 
   
   
   
         // method to change start day of the week
   public static int[] getStartEnd (int intRequestedMo) {     
      // declare array variable
      int[] intStartEndAry = new int[2];
      
      if (intRequestedMo == 2 || intRequestedMo == 3 || intRequestedMo == 11) {
         intStartEndAry[0] = 1; // mon
         intStartEndAry[1] = 7;   
      } else if (intRequestedMo == 6) {
         intStartEndAry[0] = 0; // tues 
         intStartEndAry[1] = 6;    
      } else if (intRequestedMo == 9 || intRequestedMo == 12) {
         intStartEndAry[0] = -1; // weds
         intStartEndAry[1] = 5;                
      } else if (intRequestedMo == 4 || intRequestedMo == 7) {
         intStartEndAry[0] = -2; // thurs
         intStartEndAry[1] = 4;                
      } else if (intRequestedMo == 1 || intRequestedMo == 10) {
         intStartEndAry[0] = -3; // fri
         intStartEndAry[1] = 3;        
      } else if (intRequestedMo == 5) {
         intStartEndAry[0] = -4; // sat
         intStartEndAry[1] = 2;             
      } else {
         intStartEndAry[0] = -5; // sun
         intStartEndAry[1] = 1;  
      }          
      return intStartEndAry;
   } // end getStartEnd   
   
      

      // Start of method to fill in date rows on the calendar
   public static void drawDateRow (int intDaysInMo, int intRequestedMo, int intStart, int intEnd) {
      String single = "                  ";
      String dble = "                 ";
         // for loop to create row length
      for (int i = intStart; i <= intEnd; i++) { 
         if(i <= 9 && i > 0) {
            System.out.print("|" + i + single);    
         } else if (i > 9 && i <= intDaysInMo) { 
            System.out.print("|" + i + dble);      
         } else { // handles the hanging days at the end of the month
            System.out.print("|" + single + " ");   
         }   // End of nested if/else loop to account for double digits
      }   // intEnd of for loop to draw calendar & dates
      System.out.println("|");   // Draws last pipe to complete calendar
   } // end method



   public static void drawEventRow(int intRequestedMo, int intDaysInMo, String[][] strEventArray,
      int intStart, int intEnd) {
         // declarations
      int intEvtLength;
      String strEvtName;
      int intNumSpaces;    
         // for to create row length, fill with events, or draw blanks
      for (int i = intStart; i < intEnd; i++) { // creates row length
            // if the requested day is more than 1 and less than the max days in the month
         if ( i > 0 && i <= intDaysInMo) {
               // if array slot has a value
            if (strEventArray[intRequestedMo - 1][i - 1] != null){ 
                  // get the event name from the array
               strEvtName = strEventArray[intRequestedMo - 1][i - 1];
                  // get the length of the event name
               intEvtLength = strEvtName.length();
                  // make room for the event
               intNumSpaces = 19 - intEvtLength;
                  // print the first | of the calendar design 
               System.out.print("|");
                  // print the event name
               System.out.print(strEvtName);
                  // loop to print event or blank depending on array   
               for (int k = 1; k <= intNumSpaces; k++) { 
                  System.out.print(" ");
               } // end innnermost for loop
               // if the array slot is null
            } else {
               System.out.print("|                   ");
            } // end second if/else
            // if the day number is less than 0 or more than max days of month
         } else {
            System.out.print("|                   ");
         } // end first if/else
      }// end for
   } // end drawEventRow method



      // Start of method to draw horizontal line for the calendar
   public static void drawLine() {          
       // Start of for loop to draw horizontal line for the calendar
      for (int i = 1; i <= 141; i++) { 
         System.out.print("~");
      } // End  of for loop to draw horizontal line for the calendar      
      System.out.println(); // line break
   } // End of of method to draw horizontal line for the calendar



     // Start of method to create spaces in the calendar
   public static void drawSpace() {
         // draws the blanks in the days
      for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++){               
            // Start of nested space for loop
         for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {   
            System.out.print("|                   ");
         } // End of nested space for loop         
         System.out.println("|");   // Draws last pipe to complete calendar
      } // End of method to create spaces in the calendar
   }
   
   
    
   // Start of method to draw calendar & dates together
   public static void drawCalnDate(String[][] strEventArray, int intRequestedMo) { 
          // declare variables
      int intDaysInMo;
      int[] aryStartEnd = new int[2];
            // initialize variables                     
      intDaysInMo = daysInMo(intRequestedMo);  // get num days in req'd month
      aryStartEnd = getStartEnd(intRequestedMo); // get start/end values once
         // separate the values of the array
      int intStart = aryStartEnd[0];
      int intEnd = aryStartEnd[1];     
      topDateDisp(intRequestedMo);       
         // if/else to display only required rows of weeks
      if (intRequestedMo == 2) {
           // Start of for loop to draw calendar & dates together
           // each run through the for loop draws a row
         for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {        
            drawLine();
            drawDateRow(intDaysInMo, intRequestedMo, intStart, intEnd);
            drawEventRow(intRequestedMo, intDaysInMo, strEventArray, intStart, intEnd);
            intStart += 7;
            intEnd += 7;
            drawSpace();
         }   // end for to draw cal
      } else if (intRequestedMo == 5 || intRequestedMo == 8) {
           // Start of for loop to draw calendar & dates together
           // each run through the for loop draws a row
         for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {        
            drawLine();
            drawDateRow(intDaysInMo, intRequestedMo, intStart, intEnd);
            drawEventRow(intRequestedMo, intDaysInMo, strEventArray, intStart, intEnd);
            intStart += 7;
            intEnd += 7;
            drawSpace();
         } // end for to draw cal
      } else {
           // Start of for loop to draw calendar & dates together
           // each run through the for loop draws a row
         for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {        
            drawLine();
            drawDateRow(intDaysInMo, intRequestedMo, intStart, intEnd);
            drawEventRow(intRequestedMo, intDaysInMo, strEventArray, intStart, intEnd);
            intStart += 7;
            intEnd += 7;
            drawSpace();
         } // end for to draw cal
      } // end of if/else if/else 
      drawLine();
   } // end drawCalnDate method


}// End of class
```

Comment: well then the string is not the length you think it is.  Have you stepped through the code in a debugger? That is the first thing to do.

Comment: You're right! I forgot to include the / in the date. That fixed it.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code explicitly assumes the date will have 5 characters in the form `mm/dd`, but your first input violates that assumption as it is only `1/1`.  If the date were formatted in all cases with 2-digit month and 2-digit date (i.e. `01/01`), your code would work.

You need to use the date parsing capabilities that are built-in to Java (`java.time` package).

Comment: Hi, thanks! I think it was a combo of that and I forgot to count the / when I wrote the:
if (date.length() != 4) {
Thanks for the help!